# SQL agent doesn't start after ODBC upgrade

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-agent, odbc

For security reasons, I would like to upgrade the ODBC driver from version 17 to version 18, but when I do this, the SQL agent does not start. How to configure it to start?
The log says: Windows could not start the SQL Server Agent (MSSQLSERVER) service on Local Computer. Error 1053: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.

[sqagtres] OnlineThread: Error 41d bringing resource online.

Comment: Did you uninstall ODBC driver 17? If so, reinstall it. Both drivers version can co-exist side by side.

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server Agent uses a specific version of the driver (this can and generally will be different between version) and this cannot be changed.

You're perfectly fine to add a new version but you cannot remove the older version.